# Issue authenticating SHA512 password encrypted from .NET in PHP

Tags: php, .net, encryption, passwords, sha512

I have been trying for a while now to authenticate a password encrypted in .NET from a PHP API and despite trying different ways I can't seem to get it to match.

The password was encrypted using SHA512 and stored in the database in a binary(64) field, using this exact function (which I do not have control over, it cannot be modified. No salt is used) :

```
> public byte[] GetHashablePw(string pwByte)
>     {
>         System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed sm = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();
>         System.Text.UnicodeEncoding u = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
>         byte[] b = new byte[-1 + 1];
>         b = sm.ComputeHash(u.GetBytes(pwByte));
>         return b;
>     }
```

When I want to compare the password the user supplies, I tried these different ways :

```
    $pwhash = openssl_digest($_POST['pw'], 'sha512');
    $pwhash = bin2hex(pack('H*', hash('SHA512',$_POST['pw'])));
    $pwhash = openssl_digest(utf8_decode($_POST['pw']), 'sha512');
    $pwhash = bin2hex(hash('sha512', $_POST['pw'], true));
```

which all return the same result really but none is matching what got stored in the database from .NET.

I get my password hash stored in the database with this :

```
bin2hex($pwFromDB);
```

In one particular case, I get this as a hash stored in the database:

```
4c0dc75a062dd4957f6f91350f6d3f54f910989e6ffe82749cdc580b9eae5dce0ee743cd513d005d0c399e23b0190809767fe1a57f9fecbce0a928296181c14e
```

while I get this from the PHP functions using the same password :

```
c3cf6055cbb36e3eace5ca470922de6e754ec93cf80f35459c910f4381899483e2c29565f062476724dad94929527d53eeae5a1cd708c6227574e58748d354aa
```

I would appreciate any help in understanding what I am missing.

Comment: Be aware that fast hash algorithms like SHA-* are not appropriate to hash passwords, instead use a password-hash function with a cost factor like BCrypt, SCrypt, Argon2 or PBKDF2.

Comment: @martinstoeckli
In this case I have no control over the .NET part of it so I cannot decide. 
In my usual projects I use password_hash and password_verify using PASSWORD_DEFAULT. This is fine right?

Comment: That's the recommended way yes. And if you need compatibility between DotNet and PHP you could use a dotnet [BCrypt library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt-Official/) together with `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# is using `UnicodeEncoding`, which is UTF-16LE.

You need to get the PHP data into that same representation, since cryptography operates on bytes, not text. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php might be what you want.

---

Also, the string is not encrypted. Encryption requires there be an undo operation (decryption). What has been done here is hashing. This password was *hashed*.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I thought UnicodeEncoding was ISO-8859-1 which is why I attempted the utf8_decode.